# Manual invocation of constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

Suppose I am allocating an arbitrary block of memory.  Part of this block is atomic data (ints, bytes, etc.) and some of this block of data I want to be occupied by objects.  Can I turn any arbitrary piece of memory into an object through a constructor call, such as `data->MyObject ()` and subsequently destroying the object via `data->~MyObject()`, or is this impossible?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/cs-placement-new

Comment: It's kind of the inverse of that question, actually. That question is "I've heard of placement new, what is it?" and this one is "I want to do (description of placement new's behavior), how do I do that?"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10).